# math.se feeder does not load all questions selected for more than one tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tagging, rss

First of all, trying to read or even browse all of 'linear algebra' on math.se is somewhat like trying to drink from a fire hydrant. It's too much information.

So, I solved that problem by selecting a second tag to go with it e.g. geometry that has the bene of reducing the flow of information, and giving me results that are more targeted. Fine.

When I go to google reader to pick up what math.se is laying down e.g. [linear-algebra][geometry], only the newest 30 results load into the reader. Not good. I'd like to browse all the questions that were made with both those tags.

Is anyone else having this problem, or do I need to ditch google reader?

Comment: I hoe when you say google reader, you mean a reader that's going to outlast google reader as google reader is about to close out. Have you tried a different reader?

Comment: @mixedmath - No, it's the one you are thinking of. I don't like to change, and google reader is the only one with a UI that doesn't make me want to lose my lunch. Care to make a suggestion?

Comment: @bwkaplan Netvibes in "reader" mode comes pretty close to Google Reader user experience.

Answer (score 2):

By design, RSS feed does not contain all questions with certain tags, only 30 newest. Such size limitation is present in any sensible feed, because sending entire site's content within an XML file is just not a good idea.

To avoid the limit, you can try one of the following:

1. [Bookmark this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra+geometry) and revisit it regularly.
2. Try to make [Stack2RSS](http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/) return Mathematics.SE questions. (I tried and failed. Making this CW in case someone succeeds.) 
    However, even Stack2RSS is [limited to 100 items](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126084).